# safest chmod for a file

Tags: php, linux

What is the safest chmod for a web app to write into a simple .txt file, and it should not be accessible by the public.

Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean not accessible to the public via a web server? You would need to use a `.htaccess` file to limit access.

PHP will most likely be hosted through the apache process or as a CGI probably running under the same user as the apache process, so `chmod` wouldn't work in 90% of cases.

Comment: Dont want the .htaccess to control it

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't really have a choice. Does PHP run as CGI/FCGI under a different user than Apache?? If so you could do it, but most likely you won't be able to.

Comment: assuming i am manually doing a chmod from the bash, then what could it be?

Comment: @Jean "Dont want" is quite ignorant comment.

Comment: You could use `chmod 600 FILE` to completely deny access to other users than yourself.

Comment: I can write into that file via php?

Comment: It depends on the user setup. If you're doing `chmod` via command line as the same user that PHP runs as, then yes. Otherwise no, that's kindof the point.

Comment: i do once via command line chmod, then leave it at that, and let a php app write into it

Comment: This isn't about how you do it, but instead how your users are set up. Namely, if PHP runs as the user `phpusr`, and you're running the chmod as `jean`, it's not going to work. If you're logged onto the server as `phpusr` and you run the `chmod`, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP process runs as another user, you can only allow r/w for the public. But if you mean not accessible by the public through your web server, you can use .htaccess do deny access to it.

Comment: I want to chmod directly on to it.  Could it be 744?